# Make UITableViewCell's content view overwrite accessory view

Tags: ios, swift

I've read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

And I'd like to be able to have a UITextField span the entire width of one of my static UITableViewCell's Content View, and I'd like that content view to span the entire width of the cell.

Is there a way to delete remove/disable the accessory view or reordering control?

This particular static tableview cell has user interaction disabled and simply needs to display some text.

[Here's a pic of what I'm hoping to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldHoE.png)

Comment: You can disable the accessoryView by setting `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` in `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` when dequeuing that particular cell. For the ones that you do need to have an accessory view, use `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Can I call this method for static table view cells?

Comment: I don't know, but if your cells are static, then from the storyboard just click the cell (the **cell**, not its contents) and then the accessory type will appear so it can be set to none in the right pane.

Comment: I did what you suggested in interface builder, but it did not create the change. I think my question is unclear. I'll edit now.

Comment: @AlejandroIván does the above pic help clarify?